# PROCV entre duas planilhas

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

O resultado que devo mostrar na **coluna autores da planilha produção** é o nome de todos os autores que escreveram aquela disciplina.

Estou utilizando a seguinte função `=PROCV(C8;'Remanejamento'!C3:D55;2)` mas a mesma não retorna todos os registros encontrados na **planilha Remanejamento**, mostrando apenas o último registro que achou.

O maior problema é que a mesma matéria pode ser dada em outros anos/séries e com isso, quando arrastar a fórmula para a próxima célula (caso a disciplina ainda não tenha sido pesquisada) pode sair novamente.

Abaixo mostro as colunas da planilha:

**Planilha produção**
[image: Planilha produção]

**Planilha Remanejamento**
[image: planilha Remanejamentoi]

Comment: `PROCV` obtêm um registro apenas e não todos, é a forma como funciona. Outra  forma de perceber isto é que é uma formula colocada numa célula, logo só vai gerar o valor para uma célula, dai apenas um resultado.

Comment: Você utiliza o Excel 2016? Que então você poderia utilizar o `UNIRTEXTO`

Comment: @danieltakeshi - Utilizo o Excel 2010

Comment: @Isac - Entendi. Por exemplo, quero mostrar o nome dos professores da planilha Remanejamento (pessoa 1, pessoa 2 e pessoa 3) no campo autores da planilha produção utilizando este comando =CONCATENAR(PROCV(C7;'Remanejamento'!C3:D55;2);", ";PROCV(C7;'Remanejamento'!C3:D55;2);). Só que o registro que retorna na célula é "Pessoa 3, Pessoa 3". Conhece algum outro método que poderia fazer sem repetir os nomes?

Comment: Não tenho muito contexto para aferir o que está a tentar fazer, mas se é o que eu penso então uma tabela dinâmica será uma possibilidade.

Comment: `UNIRTEXTO` realizaria a concatenação de múltiplos resultados. Porém, como sua versão não suporta esta função... Sugiro uma UDF (User Defined Function) em VBA para a sua necessidade. Ou instalar o Excel 2016... Ou cria uma coluna auxiliar e gera uma concatenação de todos os valores...

Comment: Obrigado a todos pela ajuda. Verei o que consigo fazer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente o seguinte:
Crie uma planilha chamada Auxiliar

Na planilha Auxiliar Célula A1 use a seguinte fórmula:
`=SEERRO(ÍNDICE(Remanejamento!A$2:D$18;MENOR(SE((Remanejamento!B$2:B$18=Produção!A$2)*(Remanejamento!C$2:C$18=Produção!B$2);LIN(Remanejamento!B$2:B$18)-1);LIN(L1));4);"")`

Na planilha Auxiliar Célula B1: `=SEERRO(ÍNDICE(Remanejamento!A$2:D$18;MENOR(SE((Remanejamento!B$2:B$18=Produção!A$3)*(Remanejamento!C$2:C$18=Produção!B$3);LIN(Remanejamento!B$2:B$18)-1);LIN(L1));4);"")`

Na planilha Auxiliar Célula C1: `=SEERRO(ÍNDICE(Remanejamento!A$2:D$18;MENOR(SE((Remanejamento!B$2:B$18=Produção!A$4)*(Remanejamento!C$2:C$18=Produção!B$4);LIN(Remanejamento!B$2:B$18)-1);LIN(L1));4);"")`

Na planilha Auxiliar Célula D1:
`=SEERRO(ÍNDICE(Remanejamento!A$2:D$18;MENOR(SE((Remanejamento!B$2:B$18=Produção!A$5)*(Remanejamento!C$2:C$18=Produção!B$5);LIN(Remanejamento!B$2:B$18)-1);LIN(L1));4);"")`

Na planilha Auxiliar Célula E1:
`=SEERRO(ÍNDICE(Remanejamento!A$2:D$18;MENOR(SE((Remanejamento!B$2:B$18=Produção!A$6)*(Remanejamento!C$2:C$18=Produção!B$6);LIN(Remanejamento!B$2:B$18)-1);LIN(L1));4);"")`

E copie a fórmula para baixo arrastando. (Lembrando que a função é matricial, toda vez que mexer na caixa de fórmula usar o CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER)

Na planilha Produção célula F2:`=CONCATENAR(Auxiliar!A1;" ";Auxiliar!A2;" ";Auxiliar!A3;" ";Auxiliar!A4;" "; Auxiliar!A5;" ";Auxiliar!A6)`

Na planilha Produção célula F3:`=CONCATENAR(Auxiliar!B1;" ";Auxiliar!B2;" ";Auxiliar!B3;" ";Auxiliar!B4;" "; Auxiliar!B5;" ";Auxiliar!B6)`

Na planilha Produção célula F4:`=CONCATENAR(Auxiliar!C1;" ";Auxiliar!C2;" ";Auxiliar!C3;" ";Auxiliar!C4;" "; Auxiliar!C5;" ";Auxiliar!C6)`

Na planilha Produção célula F5:`=CONCATENAR(Auxiliar!D1;" ";Auxiliar!D2;" ";Auxiliar!D3;" ";Auxiliar!D4;" "; Auxiliar!D5;" ";Auxiliar!D6)`

Na planilha Produção célula F6:`=CONCATENAR(Auxiliar!E1;" ";Auxiliar!E2;" ";Auxiliar!E3;" ";Auxiliar!E4;" "; Auxiliar!E5;" ";Auxiliar!E6)`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado por responder. Fiz os testes com  que enviou e só o comando que coloquei na célula E1 funcionou, onde que mostrava (Pessoa 1, pessoa 2, pessoa 3) mas não mostrava o resto. Realizei mais algumas pesquisas e ajuda de um colega, conseguimos resolver o problema seguindo esta instrução em VBA ->  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47837452/vba-code-to-vlookup-multiple-criteria-remove-duplicates

Comment: Fiz uma alteração e adicionei uma imagem da planilha auxiliar. Conferi as fórmulas e não encontrei erro.
@Danilo

Comment: Descobri aonde estava errando. Obrigado.